# PHP references, strange phenomenon, can someone explain?

Tags: php, loops, reference

PHP, 5.3 non thread safe window, also proven on PHP 5.2.9 on linux.

Sample code:

```
$test1 = array(
            array("val"=>"a"),
            array("val"=>"b"),
            array("val"=>"c")
          );


foreach($test1 as $key => $test)
{
    echo $test['val'] . "\n";
}
foreach($test1 as $key => &$test)
{
    echo $test['val'] . "\n";
}
foreach($test1 as $key => $test)
{
    echo $test['val'] . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
b
```

Expected output:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

So what happens? My first thought was that the array pointer was somehow involved... it wasn't `reset` did nothing. Then I thought the reference was somehow changing the values, but no, if I run it with `&test` again instead of the last one the expected output emerges, however, after the first loop using the reference, any loop WITHOUT the reference will change the last value.... this leaves me completely stumped. Can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: Exactly. The `$test` variable will live on outside the scope of the loop and will be a reference after the second loop. The third loop will then *assign* to that reference, overwriting the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looping by reference, unset($test) otherwise the reference still exists.

```
foreach($test1 as $key => &$test) 
{ 
    echo $test['val'] . "\n"; 
} 
unset($test);
```

This behaviour is [well documented](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Warning 
Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

Comment: Ugh, did actually check the documentation but completely missed it.